# apache poi: Error opening a merged word document containing an AlternateContent element

Tags: apache, ms-word, apache-poi, anchor

After merging two word documents using apache poi I get an error opening the resulting document. I copied some runs like "targetRun.getCTR().set(run.getCTR());" containing AlternateContent elements. 
One of this AlternateContent elements now is causing the mentioned error and it looks like the problem is the **id**-attribute of an **wp:docPr**-element inside of an anchor element. In this case changing the id value from 1 to 3 fixes the document.

```
<wp:drawing ..>
  <wp:anchor ..>
    <wp:docPr id="1" name="straight line1"/>
    ..
  </wp:anchor>
</wp:drawing>
```

**Does anyone know which criterias this id value should meet in addition to be unique inside the document?** I did not find an identical id value in any xml file of this docm document.

I only found this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc846345(v%3Doffice.14)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc797242(v%3doffice.14)

Comment: [Standard ECMA-376 Office Open XML File Formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) -> 20.4.2.5 docPr (Drawing Object Non-Visual Properties) -> "id (Unique Identifier): Specifies a unique identifier for the current DrawingML object within the current document. ... If multiple objects within the same document share the same id attribute value, then the document shall be considered non-conformant." Per definition it is a [3.4.22 unsignedInt](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#unsignedInt).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already checked that no objects share the same id but this does not seem to be a problem.
However, my problem was solved by modifying the word documents I get as input. Text fields on the boundaries of the document next to a table were removed and now it seems to work.